# Sketch the region $|1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}|<1$ in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that to sketch $|1+z|<1$ this is simply a circle of radius $1$ centered at $-1$ on the real axis.

I can't visualise how I would deal with the added $\frac{z^2}{2}$ term?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fvnkttj8as is a graph of it.

Answer (score 6):

We have $$1+z+\frac{z^2}{2} = \frac12(z+1)^2+ \frac12$$, so your condition is equivalent to
$$ |(z+1)^2+1| < 2 $$
$$ |(z+1+i)(z+1-i)| < 2$$
$$ |z-(-1-i)|\cdot|z-(-1+i)| < 2$$
Which means that it is a region bounded by a curve given by the condition
$$ |z-z_1|\cdot|z-z_2| = 2$$ where $z_1=-1+i$ and $z_2=-1-i$. Such a curve, for which the product of distances of points of the curve from two given foci is constant, is called [a Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval).